# Spring MVC - class member name with uppercase to lowercase, What annotation to use ?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have class with members id and parentId,

```
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String parentId;
...
```

When I read the object from DB I get in json parentId "I" with uppercase like :

[User [id=5162979b39201784891da107, parentId=1 ...

I want to have parentId in class User, but in json I want to rename it to parentid
What annotation I need to use to get in json

[User [id=5162979b39201784891da107, parentid=1 ...

Tnx

Comment: Write you own toString() method and return it

Comment: I know that there is anotation to set name to use it (not remember what exactly)

Comment: Don't change from the convention, just use parentId everywhere

Comment: This is nice workaround, but I am looking for annotation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add toString method to your class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {

    return "[id=" + getId() + ", parentid=" + getParentId() + "]";
}
```